Approximating Functions Using Combined Descent Lemma and Strongly Convex Inequality
For research purposes, I am trying to approximate both differentiable and non-differentiable functions. One of the methods I use involves combining the descent lemma and the strongly convex inequality. Specifically, I sum up these inequalities and then average them.
Recall the descent lemma:
$$f(x) \geq f(t) + \nabla f(t)^T(x-t)+\frac{L}{2} \vert\vert t-x \vert\vert ^2 , \forall t\in R$$
recall $\sigma$ strongly convex inequality:
$$f(x) \leq f(t) + \nabla f(t)^T(x-t)+\frac{\sigma}{2} \vert\vert t-x \vert\vert ^2$$
combining the 2 above and we get
$$  f(x) \approx h(x,t)= f(t) + \nabla f(t)^T(x-t)+\frac{\sigma+L}{4} \vert\vert t-x \vert\vert^2   , \forall t\in R $$
I noticed that the original function, f(x) and the approximated function h(x,t) share the same min when i substitute $t=x_{min}$. both $h(x,t=x_{min})$ and $f(x)$ share the same minimum value.
after I was shocked from this phenomena I tried to look for some papers, previous research about it but sadly I couldn't . I thought maybe anyone of you guys is familiar with this and can link me to some reading materials about it.
Thanks!
